# Outputting a DOM to HTML with &'s

Tags: java, html, xml, dom

I am trying to output a DOM that contains elements such as &nbsp; to an html file, but it will show &amp;nbsp; in the output, which is obviously not desirable. My code is as follows

```
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
    Result result = new StreamResult(output);
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), result);
```

is there anyway to get it to just output the &nbsp; (and no, replacing &nbsp; in the input is not an option )?

Comment: Don't know enough about the Transform class, but perhaps it has a disable output escaping option?

Comment: Is your input a XML document? if yes, how can it contain "&nbsp;"? it should be #160; instead?

Comment: The input is not XML, it's HTML as found on the web, therefore it does (unfortunately) contain &nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

For HTML to be valid XML including &nbsp; the document should have a DOCTYPE defining the   entity.

Adding something resembling

```
<!DOCTYPE document  SYSTEM "document.dtd" [ 
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> 
]>
```

at the beginning of the document might do it.  But this likely needs to be done to the actual source document, or prepended to it in the stream used for parsing it into the DOM.

If you post some code showing how the document referenced in your line

```
 transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), result);
```

is produced, I might conceivably be able to help more explicitly.